# Alarm application in ionic4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to develop alarm application same as default alarm application in android phone.I tried Cordova plugins but those stop working when app is closed(not minimised) Is it possible to implement using Ionic/Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

You need a plugin that uses Android's AlarmManager and allows setting alarms or notifications with sound at system level.

https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer - pretty old one

Or approach this using local notifications plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications

These notifications can feature sound and vibration, depending on your use case it may work as well.

Such notifications and alarms will act independent of whether your app is running or not.

Comment: This also doesn't work when killed an application from task manager. Only works if app is in foreground or in background.